# I can't find the button element to click on it

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping

I am trying to click on the button "View all details" to expand the details on a restaurant from OpenTable but I keep getting a no element exception. [image: Image of the wesbite]

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/chromedriver')
url = "https://www.opentable.com/chicago-illinois-restaurant-listings"
driver.get(url)

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="search_results"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a')
element.click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
    '#overview-section > div:nth-child(4) > div.f9f46391 > button').click()

driver.quit()
```

Comment: You can try doing this `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_7f28dfbb _2c55c63f a8e8f9b4 _06bf3736")[1].click();`

Answer (score 1):

Each result link has `target='_blank'` attribute. That means that if to click the link details page will be opened in new tab. To handle elements on new tab you should switch to it:

```
driver.get(url)
current = driver.current_window_handle
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.rest-row-name').click()
driver.switch_to.window([tab for tab in driver.window_handles if tab != current][0])
```

Note that you should also wait for button to became clickable:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[.="View all details"]'))).click()
```